# SSRS Calculated field problem

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to add a calculated field in a dataset with the following formula:

```
=iif(Fields!Stocabil.Value,Fields!ValoareFacturat.Value,0)
```

but using this formula, I'm not getting 0 values on false condition (Stocabil field is boolean), it's returning null probably.
I found a workaround that resolve my problem but I really don't like it. The workaround is to replace 0 with a math calculation between fields that will always be 0.

```
=iif(Fields!Stocabil.Value,Fields!ValoareFacturat.Value,Fields!ValoareFacturat.Value-Fields!ValoareFacturat.Value)
```

Is there an explanation for this?
Thank you

Comment: What data types (in the database) are Stocabil and ValoareFacturat? What are the values of each of those in the rows where you're seeing the problem? What Format specifier have you given the field in the designer? There should be something you can do with `IsNothing()` or `CDbl()` or similar, but it depends on what's actually causing the problem.

Comment: Stocabil is bit and ValoareFacturat is decimal. The values are 0 for Stocabil and 17543.3 for ValoareFacturat in one of the rows with problems. I'm not using any format specifier for the calculated field.

Comment: I just tried that, and it worked fine for me. With a simple query against SQL Server: `SELECT CAST(0 AS BIT) 'Stocabil', CAST(17543.3 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) 'ValoareFacturat'` and your exact expression, `=iif(Fields!Stocabil.Value,Fields!ValoareFacturat.Value,0)`, I get `0` displayed in the field when I run the report. Maybe there's something else going on?

Comment: Thank you Matt, you were right, using Cdbl(CalculatedField) works everywhere including totals

Comment: No problem. I've posted that as an answer, though I still can't quite see why your original wouldn't work, given what you've described...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, I can't reproduce your problem, and I can't see why what you've done shouldn't work. As discussed in the comments, though, a workaround is to use `CDbl()`, which will force the value to a double, and should display a zero for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
=iif(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Stocabil.Value),False,Fields!Stocabil.Value),Fields!ValoareFacturat.Value,0)
```